# Prim's algorithm won't compute

Tags: graph, prims-algorithm

I made a prim's algorithm but whenever i try to use the code it give me the same matrix back. In general it isn't minimizing. Can anyone check the code and let me know why it isn't minimizing my matrix

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits.h>
int minKey(int n,int key[], bool mst[])
{
   // Initialize min value
   int min = INT_MAX, min_index;

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     if (mst[i] == false && key[i] < min)
         min = key[i], min_index = i;

   return min_index;
}


void print(int n,int **matrix)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)         // print the matrix
        {
            cout << setw(2) << matrix[i][j]  << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
     }
}
int **gen_random_graph(int n)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int **adj_matrix = new int*[n];
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++)   //generating a N x N matrix  based on the # of vertex input
        {
            adj_matrix[i] = new int[n];
        }
     }

    for(int u = 0; u < n; u++)
    {
        for (int v = u; v < n; v++)      //decide whether it has an edge or not
        {
            bool edgeOrNot = rand() % 2;
            adj_matrix[u][v] = adj_matrix[v][u] = edgeOrNot;
            cout << u << " " << v << " " << adj_matrix[u][v] << endl;
            if(adj_matrix[u][v] == true)
            {
                adj_matrix[v][u] = true;
                if(u == v)                            //We can't have i = j in an undirected graph
                {
                    adj_matrix[u][v] = -1;
                }
                cout << u << " " << v << " " << adj_matrix[u][v] << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                adj_matrix[v][u] = adj_matrix[u][v] = -1;
                cout << u << " " << v << " " << adj_matrix[u][v] << "else" <<  endl;
            }
        }

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j < n; j++)           //create the N x N with edges and sets the weight between the edge randomly
        {
            if(adj_matrix[i][j] == true)
            {
                    int weight = rand() % 10 + 1;
                    adj_matrix[i][j] = adj_matrix[j][i] = weight;
                    cout << " ( " << i << "," << j << " ) " << "weight: " << adj_matrix[i][j] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    print(n,adj_matrix);
    return (adj_matrix);
}
void solve_mst_prim_matrix(int n, int **matrix)
{
     int parent[n]; // Array to store constructed MST
     int key[n];   // Key values used to pick minimum weight edge in cut
     bool mstSet[n];  // To represent set of vertices not yet included in MST

     // Initialize all keys as INFINITE
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
        key[i] = INT_MAX, mstSet[i] = false;
     }

     // Always include first 1st vertex in MST.
     key[0] = 0;     // Make key 0 so that this vertex is picked as first vertex
     parent[0] = -1; // First node is always root of MST

     // The MST will have n vertices
     for (int count = 0; count < n-1; count++)
     {
        // Pick the minimum key vertex from the set of vertices
        // not yet included in MST
        int u = minKey(n,key, mstSet);

        // Add the picked vertex to the MST Set
        mstSet[u] = true;

        // Update key value and parent index of the adjacent vertices of
        // the picked vertex. Consider only those vertices which are not yet
        // included in MST
        for (int v = 0; v < n; v++)

           // matrix[u][v] is non zero only for adjacent vertices of m
           // mstSet[v] is false for vertices not yet included in MST
           // Update the key only if matrix[u][v] is smaller than key[v]
          if (matrix[u][v] && mstSet[v] == false && matrix[u][v] <  key[v])
             parent[v]  = u, key[v] = matrix[u][v];
     }
     cout << endl;
     print(n,matrix);
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    cout << "Enter number of vertices" << endl;
    cin >> N;
    int **matrix = gen_random_graph(N);
    solve_mst_prim_matrix(N, matrix);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but after reading your code, you did not even change *any* value of `**matrix` in your `solve_mst_prim_matrix` function. So it basically prints the same thing..